# How can I change the scale of the y axis in a barplot in ggplot2 to thousands?

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale, geom-bar

I am using this code:

```
ggplot2::ggplot(DATAFRAME, aes(x = as.factor(VARIABLE))) + ggplot2::geom_bar()
```

to plot the number of occurences in each level of the variable VARIABLE in the data frame DATAFRAME. However, it is quite a long data frame, so I would like to have the counts in thousands instead of units. Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a custom function as a formatter for the `labels`. Just add this to your plot

```
+ scale_y_continuous(name = "Count (thousands)",
    labels = function(y) y / 1000)
```

For a reproducible example:

```
ggplot(data.frame(x = 1:2, y = 3:4 * 1000)) + 
    geom_point(aes(x, y)) +
    scale_y_continuous(
        name = "Axis in thousands",
        labels = function(x) x / 1000
)
```

If you want to get fancy, you could even paste `"k"` onto the end of the numbers:

```
labels = function(x) paste0(x / 1000, "k")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please explain what this: `+ scale_y_continuous(name = "Count (thousands)",
    labels = function(y) y / 1000)` does?

Comment: See `?scale_y_continuous`. If you give a function to the `labels` argument it will run that function on all your labels. You want to divide by 1000 so I give it a function that divides by 1000.

Comment: The argument name doesn't matter. `function(foo) foo / 1000` works as well as the `x` or `y` in the question. You could also define the function separately and name it, e.g., `div_by_1000 = function(bar) {bar / 1000}` and then use `labels = div_by_1000`. But if you just want to use it once, using the *anonymous* function in-line is simpler.

Comment: so the function is applied to the counts? what do you mean by "If you give a function to the labels argument it will run that function on all your labels."? Aren't the labels given by xlab() and ylab()? Are you talking about different labels?

Comment: I am talking about the axis **tick** labels. The numbers. (The ones you want to divide by 1000.) The *axis labels* you can specify by `ylab("y axis name")`, or by `labs(y = "y axis name")`, or by `scale_y_continuous(name = "y axis name")` as I do here.

Comment: The location of the tick marks will be chosen automatically, but you can customize it if you want with the `breaks` argument of `scale_y_continuous`. By default, the tick labels will be the same as the breaks, but you can change that with the `labels` argument, either by giving the labels you want as a character string or by giving a function to run on the `breaks` values.

Comment: If you need more help with this, look at the help page `?scale_y_continuous`. There are a bunch of examples at the bottom---run through them and they illustrate many different options.